# How to know what dll or services taskhost.exe is hosting?

Tags: windows, services, malware, dll, stack

I have recently discover a new process in the task manager : `taskhost.exe` (maybe it was there before but i did not notice it)

As the name implies, it seems to be used for running dll in background (like `rundll32.exe`).

**Is there a way to know which dll / services this process is hosting ?** i would like to know for which purpose it is used and if there is some malware or not.

I know it is possible to see which services `svchost.exe` process is hosting using `process explorer` utility.

I have checked `taskhost.exe` *threads* and their *stacks* using process explorer, here is what i get :

[image]

So it seems it is used for sound (*winmm* + *playsndsrv*). But there is also other things for which very few information is provided (ex : thread 1456, taskhost.exe as start address and nothing relevant can be found in stack (same for 1464, 2272 and so). So maybe it is not the right way to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Sysinternals Process Explorer hover with the mouse over the taskhost.exe entry and it will show a tooltip with the names of the tasks the process is executing.